# barplot with different colours in accordance with a condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, bar-chart

I try to make a bar-chart that shows GDP per capita in different countries so that the bars on it had different colors in accordance with the life expectancy in these countries. For now, I can create such a barplot but just with discrete values of life expectancy and not a period.

Would be perfect if countries, for example, where life expectancy is from 50 to 70 had yellow color of a bar, 70-80 - red and 80-90 - green.

Here is my code:

```
data("focusgroup")
par(mar = c(6,4,1,1))
x <- focusgroup[order(focusgroup$GDP), ]
x$color[x$`LE Both Sexes`== 55] <- 1
x$color[x$`LE Both Sexes`==77] <- 2
x$color[x$`LE Both Sexes`==77] <- 3
with(x, barplot(GDP, names.arg = x$Country, las = 2, cex.axis = 0.6, cex.lab = 0.8, cex = 0.6, col = color))
```

here is a sample of focusgroup data:
structure(Country = c("South Africa", "Swaziland", "Botswana", 
"Lesotho", "Namibia", "Sweden", "Norway", "United Kingdom", "Denmark", 
"Estonia", "Finland", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Latvia", "Lithuania", 
"New Zealand", "Australia", "South Korea", "North Korea", "China", 
"Japan", "Mongolia", "Mexico", "Costa Rica", "El Salvador", "Guatemala", 
"Honduras", "Panama", "Nicaragua"),  GDP = c(10700, 
4500, 14000, 1700, 6900, 39100, 54600, 34800, 36600, 19100, 35400, 
38300, 37300, 14700, 16000, 27700, 41000, 30000, 1800, 7600, 
34000, 3600, 13900, 11300, 7200, 5200, 4200, 13000, 3000),  Population = c(54490, 1287, 2262, 2135, 2459, 9779, 5211, 64716, 5669, 1313, 5503, 
329, 4688, 1971, 2878, 4529, 23969, 50293, 25155, 1383925, 126573, 
2959, 127017, 4808, 6127, 16343, 8075, 3929, 6082), `LE Male` = c(59.3, 
56.6, 63.3, 51.7, 63.1, 80.7, 79.8, 79.4, 78.6, 72.7, 78.3, 81.2, 
79.4, 69.6, 68.1, 80, 80.9, 78.8, 67, 74.6, 80.5, 64.7, 73.9, 
77.1, 68.8, 68.5, 72.3, 74.7, 71.5), `LE Both Sexes` = c(62.9, 58.9, 65.7, 
53.7, 65.8, 82.4, 81.8, 81.2, 80.6, 77.6, 81.1, 82.7, 81.4, 74.6, 
73.6, 81.6, 82.8, 82.3, 70.6, 76.1, 83.7, 68.8, 76.7, 79.6, 73.5, 
71.9, 74.6, 77.8, 74.8)), .Names = c("", "Country", "ISO", "Region", 
"Subregion", "Murder Rate", "Count", "GDP", "GPI", "percentage_non_religious", 
"Population", "LE Male", "LE Female", "LE Both Sexes"), row.names = c(NA, 
29L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please use `dput()` to give us a sample of the data in `focusgroup`

Comment: added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using `ggplot2` and defining the color of the barplots via the "fill" argument. Notice that I chose to rotate the axis orientation.

```
library(ggplot2)

### read data
dat <- data.frame(Country = c("South Africa", "Swaziland", "Botswana", "Lesotho", "Namibia", "Sweden", "Norway", "United Kingdom", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "New Zealand", "Australia", "South Korea", "North Korea", "China", "Japan", "Mongolia", "Mexico", "Costa Rica", "El Salvador", "Guatemala", "Honduras", "Panama", "Nicaragua"), 
                  GDP = c(10700, 4500, 14000, 1700, 6900, 39100, 54600, 34800, 36600, 19100, 35400, 38300, 37300, 14700, 16000, 27700, 41000, 30000, 1800, 7600, 34000, 3600, 13900, 11300, 7200, 5200, 4200, 13000, 3000), 
                  Population = c(54490, 1287, 2262, 2135, 2459, 9779, 5211, 64716, 5669, 1313, 5503, 329, 4688, 1971, 2878, 4529, 23969, 50293, 25155, 1383925, 126573, 2959, 127017, 4808, 6127, 16343, 8075, 3929, 6082), 
                  LE_Male = c(59.3, 56.6, 63.3, 51.7, 63.1, 80.7, 79.8, 79.4, 78.6, 72.7, 78.3, 81.2, 79.4, 69.6, 68.1, 80, 80.9, 78.8, 67, 74.6, 80.5, 64.7, 73.9, 77.1, 68.8, 68.5, 72.3, 74.7, 71.5), 
                  LE_Both_Sexes = c(62.9, 58.9, 65.7, 53.7, 65.8, 82.4, 81.8, 81.2, 80.6, 77.6, 81.1, 82.7, 81.4, 74.6, 73.6, 81.6, 82.8, 82.3, 70.6, 76.1, 83.7, 68.8, 76.7, 79.6, 73.5, 71.9, 74.6, 77.8, 74.8))
```

We can either use the continuous values in the life expectancy variable to define the fill color of the bars...

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=reorder(Country, GDP), y=GDP, fill=LE_Both_Sexes)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Country")
```

... or else use classes that we first have to create in our `data.frame`. To generate a vector with factor levels representing our classes we can use `cut`.

```
dat$LE_class <- cut(dat$LE_Both_Sexes, breaks=c(50,70,80,90), labels=c("50-70", "70-80", "80-90"))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=reorder(Country, GDP), y=GDP, fill=LE_class)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Country")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow", "red", "green")) # here's where you define the colors of the classes 
#(imho I would suggest reordering them, as c("red", "yellow", "green") seems more intuitive
```